# `time echo` got no output

Tags: zsh, time, oh-my-zsh

I'm using Mac, and I'm trying to time the command execution.

If I do

```
time echo
```

it doesn't have any output

But If I do

```
time ls
```

it does give me the output of time function

Any idea why that happens?

Update: turns out it's cuz I'm using zsh, with `oh-my-zsh` installed. It works well in bash, but no output in zsh. Any idea why?

Comment: I don't think `oh-my-zsh` is causing it.  I get the same result using zsh without that installed.  I do see time results if I do `/bin/zsh -c '/usr/bin/time echo'` though.

Comment: zsh will happily time anything in parentheses, including builtins and functions.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In zsh, the `time` keyword has no effect on builtins (or other similar shell-internal constructs). From [this mailing list post](https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2011/msg00066.html):

> Additional note:  The time builtin applied to any construct that is
>   executed in the current shell, is silently ignored.  So although it's
>   syntactically OK to put an opening curly or a repeat-loop or the like
>   immediately after the time keyword, you'll get no timing statistics. 
>   You have to use parens instead, to force a subshell, which is then
>   timed.

```
$ time echo

$ time (echo)

( echo; )  0.00s user 0.00s system 51% cpu 0.001 total
```

Answer (score -2):

The time command will spawn the command echo. Under zsh this is built into the shell so there isn't an external binary being run. Under bash, echo will run the echo binary located in /bin/echo.

So in summary zsh has echo built into itself, bash will spawn a process from the echo binary.

Comment: it's the same for some other command.. like `time rails runner "puts 'hello'"` would also give me no time

Comment: The built-in-ness of `echo` does not matter: bash also has a built-in echo  and `time echo` produces time output. There is also an echo binary, but you can try the following experiment: rename /bin/echo or /usr/bin/echo so that it cannot be executed as "echo" by bash - then try `time echo` so that the built-in is run: you still get time output.

Comment: @Nick There is no need to rename `/bin/echo`. Running `type echo` will tell you that `bash` will use the built-in when running `echo`. Built-ins always take precedence over external commands.

Comment: @Adaephon: yes, I know. I was just trying to show conclusively that when `time` runs it, it is indeed the built-in that is run and not somehow the external command.